# Spring Cloud Config vs Spring Cloud Consul Config KV

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config-server

Currently, in the project, we are using a config server. But whenever a property change happens in git we will have to either manually hit endpoints like /refresh or we should use spring cloud bus. Here instead of config server can we place our properties in Consul kV (pushing properties from git to consul)? Which is the better approach to keep in consul kV or config server (spring cloud bus) and why?